# OpenLayers 3 Resize a feature

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers 3 and OpenStreetMap for my application.
I've managed to draw circle vectors on the map to draw markers, the problem I have is that the circles have always the same size when zooming in and out.
How can I change the size of the vectors according to the resolution ?

Here is my vector definition:

```
var dealerSource = new ol.source.Vector();
function dealerStyle(feature) {
    var style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 6,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'white',
                width: 2
            }),
            anchor: [1.5, 1.5],
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'green'
            })
        })
    });
    return [style];
}
```

Comment: What I want to be able to do is the same as in this example using OpenLayers 2: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/resize-features.html

Answer (score 0):

you can change the size of your circle depending on the zoom level ( if that's what you want to do )

```
var dealerSource = new ol.source.Vector();
function dealerStyle(feature) {
    var style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: map.getView().getZoom(),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'white',
                width: 2
            }),
            anchor: [1.5, 1.5],
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'green'
            })
        })
    });
    return [style];
}
```

getZoom() returns the zoom level of your map as a number you can either use it or do a transformation on it to suit the desired size of your circle.

Note that above the bigger the zoom level is the bigger your circle will be drawn, to do the inverse you can replace the value by:

```
yourMaxZoomLevel - map.getView().getZoom()
```

you can also use getResolution() it returns a number too